# Descargar archivo desde servidor mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, archivo

Buenas compañeros, tengo un problema en mi codigo y no logro arreglarlo...

Estoy intentando subir archivos y descargarlos con php, el problema es que cuando le doy a descargar me deja la pagina en blanco y no me descarga nada..

este es mi codigo al subir el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ese es mi codigo para descargar el archivo:

```
include('conexion.php');

$id = $_GET['id']; 
$qry = "SELECT tipo, contenido, archivo FROM archivos WHERE idarchivos=".$id."";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $qry);
$tipo = mysql_result($res, 0, "tipo");
$contenido = mysql_result($res, 0, "contenido");
$nombre = mysql_result($res, 0, "archivo");

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$nombre."");
header("Content-type: ".$tipo."");

echo $contenido;
```

Comment: Te sugiero que en lugar de imágenes del código, escribas directamente el código en el texto de la pregunta.

Comment: Enviar consultas así a la BD es peligroso: `"SELECT tipo, contenido, archivo FROM archivos WHERE idarchivos=".$id.""`. Suponte que en el campo del formulario donde se escribe el `id`alguien pone esto: `1; DELETE FROM unatabla; DELETE FROM otratabla; DELETE FROM oootratabla_OMG...` estarías siendo una presa fácil de la [inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 1):

De entrada te sugiero evitar guardar el contenido del archivo en la base de datos, ya que además de tener un impacto negativo en el desempeño y en la utilización de espacio, se requiere código especial para leer y escribir datos cuando el tamaño excede cierto límite (32KB si mal no recuerdo).

La mejor práctica es guardar en la base de satos únicamente una referencia o la ruta del archivo de tal manera que al momento de que se solicite la descarga, leas de la base de datos únicamente la ruta (o los datos necesarios para construir la ruta) y después en PHP abras directamente el archivo para la descarga.

Comment: Ya intente eso que me estas sugiriendo y me dice que no tengo el permiso para descargar el archivo

Comment: cambiale los permisos al archivo directamente, no necesitas hacer muho @Jesús

Comment: @Jesús en ese caso te sugiero que hagas otra pregunta en la que especifiques el código utilizado y el error que se genera.  Normalmente si el proceso que guardó el archivo tiene permisos para escribir en la carpeta, debe tener permisos para leer el archivo.  Es probable que esté fallando la función `move_uploaded_file` por lo que debes revisar el valor que devuelve.

Comment: @Jesús la mejor forma, es lo que te comenta en la respuesta que te dan. Es es guardar la referencia en la BD y el archivo en un directorio. y una vez que lo tenga en el directorio y la referencia en la bd solo tienes que llamarlo con un **href** desde la página. Por favor puedes poner el código fuera de una imagen para ayudarte con el código con los cambios que hay que hacer.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez eso lo entiendo y lo tengo hecho, el problema es que estoy buscando un paciente por cedula, me devuelve el dato y todo.. pero al momento de darle a descargar me deja la pagina en blanco... <a href='controlador/documento.php?idarchivos=<?=$row['id']?>' target="_blank">Descarga tu Documento</a> lo tengo de esa manera que llama al controlador de documento.php

Comment: @Jesús puedes colocar fuera de la imagen el código donde hace la descarga para hacerte una modificaciones y pruebes ya que me comentas que tienes el fichero físico y la referencia en la base de datos.

Comment: listo @YoelRodriguez

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo el cambio, para que llames directamente al fichero sin necesidad de imprimir el contenido:

```
include('conexion.php');

$id = $_GET['id']; 
$qry = "SELECT tipo, contenido, archivo FROM archivos WHERE idarchivos=".$id."";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $qry);
$nombre = mysql_result($res, 0, "archivo");

header("Location: subir_archivo/archivos".$nombre.);
```

> Nota: la ruta donde esta el archivo físico verificarla porque no la logro ver bien. El nombre de la referencia tiene que estar completo con la extensión no puede estar separado.

Comment: me podrias pasar tu gmail para mandarte la prueba de lo que estoy haciendo.. asi lo vez mejor..

Comment: mamelonado al que tengo aquí en el sitio es el que uso no tengo gmail

Comment: Tranquilo lo acabo de resolver.. ya me funciona el codigo :D.. gracias por la ayuda amigo

Comment: Hola  y como fue la solución final, si gusta la puedes publicar para si a otra persona le hace.falta.